# why does as.integer in R decrement the value?

Tags: r

I am doing a simple operation of multiplying a decimal number and converting it to integer but the result seems to be different than expected. Apologies if this is discussed else where, I am not able to find any straight forward answers to this

```
> as.integer(1190.60 * 100)
[1] 119059
```

**EDIT:**
So, I have to convert that to character and then do as.integer to get what is expected

```
> temp <- 1190.60
> temp2 <- 1190.60 * 100
> class(temp)
[1] "numeric"
> class(temp2)
[1] "numeric"
> as.character(temp2)
[1] "119060"
> as.integer(temp2)
[1] 119059
> as.integer(as.character(temp2))
[1] 119060
```

**EDIT2**: According to the comments, thanks @andrey-shabalin

```
> temp2
[1] 119060
> as.integer(temp2)
[1] 119059
> as.integer(round(temp2))
[1] 119060
```

**EDIT3:** As mentioned in the comments the question is related to behaviour of as.integer and not about floating calculations

Comment: So I have to convert that to character first and then use as.integer

Comment: What is the reason you need it as integer?

Comment: I suggest rounding the number first, not converting to character.
`as.integer(round(temp))`

Comment: This is a floating-point accuracy issue: `temp2-119060 = -1.455192e-11`

Comment: close as duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal ?

Comment: @BenBolker thought about that, but that question doesn't really talk about the behaviour of `as.integer`, which seems to be the core question here. Obviously this is floating point stuff, but the answer here is the rounding behaviour of `as.integer`.

Comment: From the documentation of `as.integer()`: *Non-integral numeric values are truncated towards zero *

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are these numbers not equal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to this is "floating point error". You can see this easily by checking the following:

```
> temp <- 1190.60
> temp2 <- 1190.60 * 100
> temp2 - 119060
[1] -1.455192e-11
```

Due to floating point errors, temp2 isn't exactly 119060 but :

```
> sprintf("%.20f", temp2)
[1] "119059.99999999998544808477"
```

If you use `as.integer` on a float, it works the same way as `trunc`, i.e. it does round the float in the direction of 0. So in this case that becomes 119059.

If you convert to character using `as.character()`, R will make sure that it uses maximum 15 significant digits. In this example that would be "119059.999999999". The next digit is another 9, so R will round this to 119060 before conversion. I avoid this in the code above by using `sprintf()` instead of `as.character()`.

Comment: What about round(), does that follow the same semantics used for as.character() rounding ?

Comment: @pshirishreddy how so what about round? round() works as advertised on its help page: it rounds to the nearest integer. So `as.integer(round(temp2))` gives you what you'd expect.